# Tool Compare the tables in two different databases

Tags: sql, database, unix, toad

I am using Toad. Frequently i need to compare tables in two different test environments.
the tables present in them are same but the data differs.
i just need to know what are the differences in the  same tables which are in two different data bases.Are there any tools which can be installed on windows and use it to compare.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index.htm) and [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql_data_compare/index.htm)

Answer (score 3):

There's a compare tool built into TOAD.  Tools | Compare Data.

Answer (score 1):

Open Source DiffKit will do this:

www.diffkit.org

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely go with [AdeptSQL](http://www.adeptsql.com/) if you're using MSSQL. It's the least good looking but the most talented db compare tool amongst the ones I've tried. It can compare both the structure and the data. It tells you which tables exist on one db but does not exist on the other, compares the structure and data of the common ones and it can produce the script to synchronize the two. It's not free but has a 30 day trial (as far as I can remember)

Answer (score 0):

Try [dbForge Data Compare for SQL Server](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/datacompare/). It can compare and sync any databases, even very large ones. Quick, easy, always delivers a correct result.
Try it on your database and comment upon the product.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it online, there is a free tool [**DB Matcher**](https://dbmatcher.com) where you upload 2 `.SQL` files and it gives you the differences

https://dbmatcher.com